# Meson on windows cannot find llvm-lib?

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, meson-build

I am trying to port a Linux Library to windows, the library uses meson for compilation. I have a dummy meson.build file:

```
project(
    'Dummy',
    'cpp',
    version: '0.0.1',
    license: 'GPL',
    default_options : [
        'cpp_std=c++latest',
        'default_library=static',
        'optimization=3',
        'buildtype=debugoptimized'])
```

When I run `meson configure` I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Makogan\Documents\neverengine\build> meson compile
[0/1] Regenerating build files.
The Meson build system
Version: 0.60.3
Source dir: C:\Users\Makogan\Documents\neverengine
Build dir: C:\Users\Makogan\Documents\neverengine\build
Build type: native build
Project name: NeverEngine
Project version: 0.0.1
C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.13.26131.1 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.13.26131.1 for x64")
C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.13.26131.1

..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown linker(s): [['lib'], ['llvm-lib']]
The following exception(s) were encountered:
Running "lib /?" gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running "llvm-lib /?" gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

A full log can be found at C:\Users\Makogan\Documents\neverengine\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
FAILED: build.ninja 
"C:\Python311\Scripts\meson" "--internal" "regenerate" "C:\Users\Makogan\Documents\neverengine" "C:\Users\Makogan\Documents\neverengine\build" "--backend" "ninja"
ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
```

Why is meson automatically searching for these libraries when it is aware it is on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't libraries, those are static linkers (also called archivers), which are used to produce static libraries (those ending in .a or .lib, usually). Those are pretty important to meson, and it assumes that it can find the three pieces of the toolchain (The compiler, the archiver, and the [dynamic] linker) for any given language + machine.

It is interesting to me that meson is able to pick up the cl.exe and link.exe, but not lib.exe